# Java passing a newly created object as method argument inside the constructor of that object

Tags: java, arguments, this

I am trying to implement the UCS algorithm for a game in Java and I am now in the stage where I need to calculate the costs of each state.

I made a `Node` class with 4 fields (a `Table` *state*, `double` *cost*, a `Node` *parent* and an `ArrayList<Node>` *children*)  where i have a `private static double calculateCost(Node starting, Node next)` method, which returns the cost of transitioning from the `starting` node to the `next` node.

*Ignore the Table class, there is no need to explain what it does.*

I also made the following `generateChildren()` method:

```java
public void generateChildren(){
    ArrayList<Table> allStates = this.state.generateMoves();

    for(Table state : allStates){
        Node child = new Node(state, calculateCost(this, ???), this);

        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

It generates all the possible moves from a given state, and for each move it creates a child.

What I want is to pass `child` as the second argument of the `calculateCost()`, so that `this` object is the starting Node, and the `child` is the next Node. Is it possible at all?

Comment: No, this does not seem possible. There is an alternative way I can think of. Create the child node using only the state and this parameters. Then calculate cost and call a setter method in the child node to set the cost.

Comment: Stelios, have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could completely remove the `calculateCost(this, ???)` parameter, and instead move it into the Node constructor. You haven't posted what the Node constructor currently looks like, so the below code is simply a template that you can map to your current solution:

```java
class Node {
    * before constructor *

    Node(Table state, Node parent) {
        this.state = state;
        this.parent = parent;

        this.cost = calculateCost(parent, this);

        * rest of constructor *
    }

    * after constructor *
}
```

This should give the desired effect. Your `generateChildren` method would now look like:

```java
public void generateChildren(){
    ArrayList<Table> allStates = this.state.generateMoves();

    for(Table state : allStates){
        Node child = new Node(state, this);

        children.add(child);
    }
}
```